# a minha pagina de entrada é 1920x1080 mas com um scrool nela

Tags: html, css, front-end

quero tirar o scrool da pagina mas quando ponho o position: fixed isso corta a pagina e quando ponho o position: abosolute, fica com um scrool igual na pagina apresentada
se alguem tiver a solução por favor me responder, obrigado.

[image: como podemos ver ter um scrool em baixo e na lateral]

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    }
.body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en">


<head>
   
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="teste pagina entrada color design.css">
   
    <title>Document</title>

</head>


<body class="body">
    
    <img class="Layer_1" src="file:///C:/projetos/Color%20design/Layer%201.png">
    
    <img class="Logo_Branco" src="file:///C:/Users/Caio/Pictures/imagem%20color%20design/Logo%20branco.png">
    
    <h1 class="OUR">OUR</h1>
    
    <h1 class="COLORS">COLORS</h1>

</body>


</html>
```

se alguem tiver a solução por favor me responder, obrigado

Comment: use medidas em percentual, já pensou que nem todos tem o monitor que suporte essa resolução? se usar percentual vai ficar bom em qualquer monitor/dispositivo

Comment: é  sobre  uma imagem?

Comment: Ricardo Pontual obrigado pela dica, ja consegui

Answer (score 0):

Usa esse CSS

```css
    .Layer_1 {
        position: fixed; 
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        //min-width: 100%; 
        //min-height: 100%;
        //z-index: -1;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


    <html lang="en">


    <head>
       
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
       
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="teste pagina entrada color design.css">
       
        <title>Document</title>

    </head>


    <body class="body">
        
        <img class="Layer_1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhbVP.jpg">
        
        <img class="Logo_Branco" src="">
        
        <h1 class="OUR">OUR</h1>
        
        <h1 class="COLORS">COLORS</h1>

    </body>


    </html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] clica em Executar e depois em Pagina toda no canto direito